# Filter Menu Popup for Search Screen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, filter, widget

I wanted to create a Search Screen in Flutter and use a button to open a menu on the bottom, where filters could be changed. Now I don't want to implement the logic just yet, I just want to be able to display the UI as below. Here is the Code I have for the normal Search Screen

```
class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchScreen> createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  Color filterColor = backgroundColor;
  bool filterStat = false;
  int prefIndex = 0;
  List<String> prefSearch = [
    ' Lunch',
    ' Dinner',
    ' Party',
    ' Healthy',
    ' Sweet',
    ' Spicy',
  ];
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                HomeScreenHeader(
                  subText: 'Explore',
                  mainText: 'Wine and Food',
                  boxWidth: 184,
                ),
                const SearchBar(),
                Positioned(
                  left: 35,
                  top: 172,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 400,
                    height: 25,
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: [
                        FilterCard(prefSearch: prefSearch, prefIndex: 0),
                        FilterCard(prefSearch: prefSearch, prefIndex: 1),
                        FilterCard(prefSearch: prefSearch, prefIndex: 2),
                        FilterCard(prefSearch: prefSearch, prefIndex: 3),
                        FilterCard(prefSearch: prefSearch, prefIndex: 4),
                        FilterCard(prefSearch: prefSearch, prefIndex: 5),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 35,
                  top: 215,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 78,
                    width: 160,
                    child: Text(
                      'Found 40 results',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 26,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: mainTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 35,
                  top: 303,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 1000,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        
                        // PrefInformationCard(
                        //   wineName: 'Healthy',
                        // ),
                        // PrefInformationCard(
                        //   wineName: 'Healthy',
                        // ),
                        // PrefInformationCard(
                        //   wineName: 'Helathy',
                        // ),
                        // PrefInformationCard(
                        //   wineName: 'Healthy',
                        // ),
                        // PrefInformationCard(
                        //   wineName: 'Healthy',
                        // ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 210,
                    top: 218,
                  ),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 1000,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        PrefInformationCard(
                          wineName: 'Spaghetti',
                        ),
                        PrefInformationCard(
                          wineName: 'Spaghetti',
                        ),
                        PrefInformationCard(
                          wineName: 'Spaghetti',
                        ),
                        PrefInformationCard(
                          wineName: 'Spaghetti',
                        ),
                        PrefInformationCard(
                          wineName: 'Spaghetti',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FilterCard extends StatefulWidget {
  FilterCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.prefSearch,
    required this.prefIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);
  List<String> prefSearch;
  int prefIndex;
  @override
  _FilterCardState createState() => _FilterCardState();
}

class _FilterCardState extends State<FilterCard> {
  Color filterColor = backgroundColor;
  bool filterStat = false;

  TextStyle textStyle = unTextStyle;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          right: 10,
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (filterStat == false) {
                filterColor = primaryColor;
                textStyle = selTextStyle;
              }
              if (filterStat == true) {
                filterColor = backgroundColor;
                textStyle = unTextStyle;
              }
              if (filterColor == backgroundColor) {
                filterStat = false;
              }
              if (filterColor == primaryColor) {
                filterStat = true;
              }
            });
          },
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(
              milliseconds: 250,
            ),
            width: 70,
            height: 25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: filterColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
              border: Border.all(color: primaryColor),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                widget.prefSearch[widget.prefIndex],
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: textStyle),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: Normal Search Screen]

[image: Search Screen with Filter Menu]

Thanks for the help in advance :)